# Carbon::now displaying wrong time unless formatted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-carbon, php-8

I have an issue with the time returned from my database, everything is 2 hours in the past.

I've been troubleshooting this issue for a bit, and checked the following:

/etc/php.ini is only ini in use and has `date.timezone = Europe/Amsterdam`.(also restarted apache)

Laravel's app.php config has `'timezone' => 'Europe/Amsterdam'`.

I ran `config:clear` and `config:cache`.

I was able to boil the issue down to Carbon.

I have a route which simply returns `Carbon::now()` and it shows `2021-07-09 10:58:31.874837Z` (2 hours early)

If I modify the code to `Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")` it returns `2021-07-09 12:58:31` which is the correct time.

If I run tinker, and then run `Carbon/Carbon::now()` it directly shows the correct time(locally on Win 10 AND on the centos server)

I'm not sure why carbon shows a different time when formatted, did I miss a config somewhere?

Thank you in advance.

#### NOTE:

If I use tinker, I'm getting the correct time from both my DB(which's timezone is CEST) and `Carbon::now()`

Answer (score 2):

You open with

> I have an issue with the time returned from my database, everything is 2 hours in the past.

Your database might be the key here: Does the data stored there come with a timezone? Is it expected in a specific timezone? The database probably returns UTC, which is exactly 2h off of CET (Amsterdam time) during summer. And your application interprets this time as CET. Thus, the time is 2h behind

My recommendation is to **not** bother with timezones anywhere in the technical layer and only format to the user's timezone in the UI. E.g. have all your servers run on UTC only. Store time in UTC. Calculate whatever you need in UTC. And for display, convert to the current user's preferred timezone.

And that recommendation might be precisely what you're running into: Your database just stores UTC times, which you interpret as CET. Don't do that. It'll result in a mess with the next change to daylight saving time in autumn of this year.

Add on:

Even (or especially) after your note, I stand by what I wrote above: Have *all* your technical infrastructure *purely* work on UTC, *always*. This means there will never ever be any conversion until the very last moment, when the time is converted to the user's preferred timezone. Or if there is, it's trivial to find the culprit. All hell breaks lose when you routinely involve timezone math in all operations (other than to/from UTC conversions). Especially around the time of daylight saving time changes (which happen at different dates in different regions, and in different directions on both hemispheres)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a note to my question, stating that my DB has the 'correct' timezone (CEST) and via tinker, I'm getting the correct time from both my DB and `Carbon::now()`. It is only failing when the code is being runned via the webserver, not via CLI. It seems like the webserver misinterprets the time for some reason, but I cannot see where. I wonder if your solution of keeping everything UTC will adequatly resolve the issues, or that I'm going to run into more issues.

Comment: See my answer, I bet your statement about "Carbon::now() and it shows 2021-07-09 10:58:31" is actually incomplete, what output are you talking about? a view, a JSON, a plain text response? Each can convert/format date differently and that matters, then what is the complete output of the date? Are you very sure `"2021-07-09 10:58:31"` is the exact string you got as output? Because I can't see how this could happen that you would get that from `Carbon::now()` so I suspect you took a shortcut in describing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a route which simply returns Carbon::now() and it shows 2021-07-09 10:58:31 (2 hours early)
>
> If I modify the code to Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") it returns 2021-07-09 12:58:31 which is the correct time.

What is "show" in the first sentence, because, this is not possible that the object would have a different timezone or value that what you see when you format it using `format("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

`2021-07-09 10:58:31` here is the result of the datetime converted into UTC.

So my guess is that you're talking about a JSON output, and what you see is actually `2021-07-09T10:58:31Z` and not `2021-07-09 10:58:31`, in this case it's correct, the `Z` here is very important to be kept as it means "Zulu = GMT" and will allow the JSON reader (such as a web browser) to construct the correct date anywhere on earth while if `2021-07-09 12:58:31` would be returned, the reader would have no clue what timezone it is.

Comment: I have to be honest, I did make a mistake in the explaination, as you mentioned in the other comment. It does add the `Z`  at the end(edited the question) I was unaware that this communicates with the webbrowser/json-reader. Thank you for the info, that really helps. Now I think I only need to setup chrome to do the formatting correctly.